# Approximating a Sobolev function by Schwartz functions

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let $f$ be a smooth bounded function, and suppose moreover that $f \in W^{k,2} (\mathbb{R^n})$ for all $k \geq 0$.

Fix a natural number $k_0$.
I want to show that there exists a sequence of Schwartz functions $f_n$ such that $f_n \to f$ in $W^{k_0,2}$ and pointwise everywhere.

I tried:

By molification, I can show that there exists such a sequence consisting of merely smooth $f_n$.

I tried to truncate $f_n$ to get Schwartz functions, but then I cannot control the $W^{k_0 ,2 }$ norms.

How should I proceed?

Comment: Truncate $f$ first with smooth cutoff functions, then mollfify.

Comment: @HansEngler  I wonder if $f(\cdot ) \chi (\frac{\cdot}{n})  $ converges to $f$ in the Sobolev norm as $n$ increases. (Here, $\chi $ denotes a smooth cutoff.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose $k_1 > \max(k_0, \frac{n}{2})$. There exists a sequence $f_n \in \mathcal{S}$ such that $f_n \to  f$ in $W^{k_1,2}$. Therefore (by standard embedding) this convergence is also in $W^{k_0,2} \cap L^\infty$.